# How to make Entries with the same size but different fonts in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I need to make two *identical Entries* in a same row, but each Entry's text have a *different font*. I tried setting a fixed width to both entries, but the Font modifies it. Is there any way to set a fixed size to an Entry regardless its size?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Answer (score 2):

Don't set the Entry size, set the size of whatever container they are in. As you say "row" I assume you are using a grid layout. This would be a good place to use the completely undocumented "uniform" argument.

```
frame.columnconfigure([0,1], uniform='entrycol') # set columns 0 and 1 to the same width

ent = tk.Entry(frame, width=2) # set the width small to start
ent.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ew') # set the entry to stick to the east and west
```